# Left Join two columns with the same type of data, different values

Tags: sql

In my table I have two columns, `cars.station1_id` and `cars.station2_id`.  These columns contain an ID number referencing `stations.id`.

I need to take the two ID's and retrieve `stations.name` for each of them.

How do I do this?

This is my code to join one column:

`SELECT station1_id, station2_id FROM cars`
`LEFT JOIN stations`
`ON stations.id = cars.station_id`

Comment: What is cases.station_id

Comment: Can both station_id references for a car record be populated, or will it always only be one of them?

Comment: @d03boy Oops, I meant `cars.station_id`

Comment: @OMG Ponies: Both references can be populated

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT a.name, b.name
FROM cars
LEFT JOIN stations a ON a.id = station_id
LEFT JOIN stations b ON b.id = station2_id
```

Answer (score 2):

The key is to use a different alias each time.
`s1` and `s2` in this case:

```
SELECT station1_id, station2_id 
  FROM cars
       LEFT JOIN stations s1
       ON s1.id = cars.station1_id
       LEFT JOIN stations s2
       ON s1.id = cars.station2_id
```